# location on change view issue angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Stuck in an issue where i have to check authentication when location changes:

**Issue**:

while on location change i request the back-end to check auth if response is not 401 then show the page otherwise redirect to login page, when response is 401 the page shows for a bit and then the redirection happens to login page , for me its a headache because the page shows for a bit and then location changes , someone help me please?

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
    var publicPages = [''];


    $rootScope.showPreloader = true;
    AuthenticationService.Login(function (_data) {
        if (_data.result) {
            count  =1;
            localStorage.setItem('userInfo', angular.toJson(_data.result));
            awtcDataService.employeeInfo = _data.result;
            var roles = awtcDataService.employeeInfo
            var route = localStorage.getItem('setRoute')

                if (route == '/check') {
                    $state.go('help');
                }
                else {
                    $state.go('home');
                }

        }
        if (_data.status === 401) {
            $state.go('login', {reload: true})//shows the page e.g home and then redirects to this page
            count  =1;
            event.preventDefault();
            return;
            $timeout(function(){
                console.log("show after directive partial loaded")
            });

        }
        else {

        }
    }, function (error) {
        if (error.status === 401) {
            $state.go('login', {reload: true})/shows the page sometimes e.g home and then redirects to this page
            count  =1;
            event.preventDefault();
            return;
            $timeout(function(){
                console.log("show after directive partial loaded")
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All state events, (i.e. $stateChange* and friends) are now deprecated and disabled by default. Instead of listening for events, use the Transition Hook API.

https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#state-change-events

Comment: stateChangeStart not detetcing by app

Comment: are u injecting 'ui.router', to ur root module?

Comment: All state events, (i.e. $stateChange* and friends) are now deprecated and disabled by default. Instead of listening for events, use the Transition Hook API.

Comment: Looks like $stateChangeStart is deprecated

Comment: https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#state-change-events

Comment: which version of angular u are using?

Comment: currently using 1.5x